# Angularjs radio buttons

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs

I know that this has been spoken about in some Google Threads but I still can't find the right solution to bind my radio inputs to a model (in clean'n simple manner),

Currently I have HTML:

```
<input ng-model="searchByRma" type="radio" name="search-type">
<input ng-model="searchByDelivery" type="radio" name="search-type">
```

And in Controller:

```
$scope.searchByRma      = true;
$scope.searchByDelivery = false;
```

This does not work (as it would with the checkboxes)...

Any ideas on how to set the default value on the first radio button without loosing data-binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think you should use same variable with different values in those
two radio buttons.

```
<input ng-model="searchBy" value="Rma" type="radio" name="search-type">
<input ng-model="searchBy" value="Delivery" type="radio" name="search-type">
```

Then, you should have `searchBy` set either "Rma" or "Delivery" depending on
user input.

Comment: That's perfect, I also had ng-checked set on one of the radio buttons that was breaking it, so it might be helpful for someone... Thanks!!!

Comment: Why for example is this also working perfectly but it doesn’t when the type=‘radio’ ??? <input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>

Answer (score -1):

What has worked for me is to set the model variable to { } and that will reset the radio buttons to their default (not selected) state. Of course, this will only work if you have your radio button tags correct as in tosh's answer.

In your case:

```
$scope.searchBy = { };
```