# ng-model not updating with radio button

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a problem with angular and I'm not understanding what the problem may be:

thats a div:

```
<div ng-controller="CountrySelectorController">
            Selected Countryid = {{countryid}}
            <div class="radio" ng-repeat="country in countries">
                <input type="radio" name="countryOptions" ng-model="countryid" value={{country.countryid}} ng-checked="countryid == country.countryid" /><span style="margin-left:10px;">{{country.countryid}}.{{country.name}}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
</div>
```

thats my controller:

```
app.controller('CountrySelectorController', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.countryid = 1;
});
```

the problems I'm getting:
-Selected Countryid=1 appears at start . Although I'm selecting different countries, the model is not updating

Comment: You should not have used ng-checked.

Comment: Check this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597138/angularjs-radio-buttons

Comment: @dotnetstep, I used the checked, its ok, but the model is not udpdating, Selected Countryid always stays 1

Comment: @Braulio, that's how I'm doing it, using the radio button with the same model, same name and different values

Comment: Sorry about that, Jerrad is right, another way to avoid the $parent stuff is to wrap your scope visible data in a "model", somethig like $scope.model.countryid, then in your ng-model you would use something like ng-model="model.countryid"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-repeat creates its own scope, which is not what you want to bind the ng-model to.  You want to bind ng-model to the controller's scope (which is the parent scope of the ng-repeat).
Use $parent to go up a level to the correct scope.  Also, don't use ng-checked.

```
ng-model="$parent.countryid"
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/xoquh/1/edit)

Comment: thanks man, it works, this one, the fact that ng-repeat creates its own scope, I didn't know