# AngularJS radio button validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple and easy.

I got two radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="male">
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="female">
```

How do i validate in AngularJS that at least one is chosen? And how can i type something like

```
$scope.myForm.gender.$invalid
```

Any ideas?

Comment: might this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597138/angularjs-radio-buttons?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Radio Button AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685664/validate-radio-button-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **required** :

```
   <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="male" required>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="female" required>
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdgAywfC6mu7gL9SxPpC?p=preview)

same Question asked here : [Validate Radio Button AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685664/validate-radio-button-angularjs)

Comment: Why for example is this working perfectly but it doesn’t when the type=‘radio’ ??? <input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>

Answer (score 1):

Without a form, you can fix this by check the value of the models in your controller, returning an error if both are false. You could also go ahead and set one true by default.

But to answer your question, you can do something similar to `$scope.myForm.gender.$invalid` all you have to do is wrap your input tags in a form with the name myForm. So, it would like:

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="male">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="female">
</form>
```

Then, `$scope.myForm` would be able to give you certain properties, like `$isPristine` and properties for each input field.

Either of these ways will work though, so I help that helps!